# Add context to head of ListAPIView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like to add `{'user': self.request.user}` to the header of my ListAPIView.

For example, the JSON response would look like:

```
[
    'user': testing_user,
    {
        id: 67,
        slug: "slugy",
    },
]
```

Is it possible to do this with this view?

```
class BookArchiveAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    cache_timeout = 60 * 7
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
```

Comment: I've never used DRF but that structure doesn't make much sense, because an api shouldn't mix a list of stuff with type `Book` and a `user`. Can't you build a separate api to query just the user?

Comment: @ShangWang To display certain items on my iPhone app, I need to see the current user viewing the api. I could make two url requests, but obviously one would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know its too late but I needed same thing and just found on the documentation easily.

You don't need to pass the "request.user" to the view because DRF already gives it to you.

***Here is the example:***

```
class show_activities(generics.ListAPIView):
serializer_class = ActivitySerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    username = self.request.user.username
    return Activity.objects.filter(owner=username)
```

It's easy to find on documentation but I'm answering for the ones who couldn't see it.